# when I log as root, the GUI is frozen

Tags: root

I have a ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server and there I have some virtual machines that run from the root account. Today I needed to check one of the virtual machines, so I tried to connect to the root GUI and altough I got logged in, the GUI is frozen.

Is there a way to recover from that without rebooting the server?

Comment: You are not supposed to login as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try switch in another TTY (Alt + F1 as example). In the TTY kill or restart your GUI session.